# Nginx proxy pass by query param

Tags: nginx, query-string, proxypass

I need to proxy pass web sockets with Nginx that follow those rules :

**Proxy only URL 1** :

ws_api/account/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/messaging/brand/*

**But not URL 2** :

any url with query param (brand_request_type=ums)

ws_api/account/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/messaging/brand/*/?brand_request_type=ums

I have succeeded to proxy 1 but unable to ignore any URL with the query param.

I tried to ignore URL 2 with regex.

Here is the code :

My home domain is: http://homeDomain
The new domain is: http://newDomain

```
 location  ~ ws_api/account/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/messaging/brand/ {

    proxy_pass http://newDomain;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 70;

    }  

    location  ~ ws_api/account/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/messaging/brand/*/(\bbrand_request_type=ums\b) {

    proxy_pass http://homeDomain;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 70;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer ,
there is a problem in the query param , preferred to give a name without '_'

Here is the solution :

**Proxy only URL 1 :**

ws_api/account/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/messaging/brand/*

**But not URL 2 :**

any url with query param (myqueryparam=ums)

ws_api/account/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/messaging/brand/*/?myqueryparam=ums

Here is the code :

My home domain is: http://homeDomain The new domain is: http://newDomain

```
 location  ~ ws_api/account/le50585563/messaging/brand/ {

 set $pp_d newDomain;

 if ($arg_myqueryparam ~ "ums") {
    set $pp_d homeDomain;
 }

proxy_pass http://$pp_d;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_read_timeout 70;

}
```